# How does some non-polar molecules dissolve in water?

Tags: physical-chemistry

My textbook says:

> Similarly, **non-polar (*i.e.*, covalent or organic) compounds** like naphthalene, anthracene etc. are soluble in non-polar (*i.e.*, covalent or organic) solvents like benzene, ether, carbon tetrachloride, etc. and **are very little soluble in water**.

My question is that if we have a non polar compound, then it seems as if it should not dissolve to any extent.  However, the quote says that non polar molecules are a little soluble in water.  Thus I want to know why non polar solutes dissolve in water at all, even if it is only to a very lesser extent?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misconception that polar and nonpolar molecules (or rather, strongly polar and weakly polar) tend to repel one another.  However, they actually attract one-another—due a combinations of weak dipole-dipole forces (which exist even for molecules with very small dipole moments) and [van der Waals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) forces (which are really quantum-mechanical dipole-dipole forces, in which one of both of the dipoles is virtual).  The reason then that polar and nonpolar liquids tend to separate is that the polar molecules are attracted to one-another much more strongly than they are attracted to the nonpolar molecules.

There is thus an energy cost to inserting a nonpolar molecule in the midst of a liquid of polar molecules like water, because doing so breaks up the network of attractive links between the charged ends of the molecular dipoles.  However—and this is really the answer to the question—energetics is not entirely responsible for the equilibrium of a solution; there are also entropy effects.  The thermal equilibrium state of a solution minimizes not the energy $E$, but rather the ["free energy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_free_energy)  $F=E-TS$.  Having a few of the nonpolar molecules in solution increases the entropy $S$ of the system quite a bit, and so at finite temperature (and no real substances except helium remain liquids down to zero temperature), the entropic effect means there is a balance between the energy cost and entropy gain of having molecules in solution.  And as the temperature rises, the influence of the entropy increases, leading to the well-known increase in solubility with $T$.

From [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics), we understand that what the entropy change means at a microscopic level is simply that there are far more possible states in which some of the nonpolar molecule are intermixed among the polar solvent molecules than states in which none of them them are in solution.  Therefore, if you choose a random state in an energy range described by a given temperature (and at any given time, the state of a real physical system in thermodynamic equilibrium is essentially just such a random one), it is overwhelmingly likely that you will find one in which some of the nonpolar molecules are dissolved.  In terms of microscopic dynamics, the net forces on molecules will gradually tend to exclude the nonpolar molecules from the polar solution, but the rate at which the nonpolar molecules reach the surface and drop *out* of solution is balanced by thermal fluctuations that occasionally knock undissolved nonpolar molecules *into* the solution.