# How does non-polar solutes dissolve in non-polar solvents?

Tags: physical-chemistry

My actual question is that i want to know the molecular interaction can all takes place between non polar solvents and non polar solutes and also i want to know that why does some non polar substance dissolve in water like sugar??

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/775290/2451

Comment: This is a terrible formatted question, but I will give you the hint that the overall answer lies in entropy. The only reason that the forces of attraction that hold together like particles would spontaneously break down is because there is an overall energetic benefit to doing so, and that comes from the entropy gained by the various particles being solvated. This question also belongs on the chemistry site, not the physics one IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The interactions that make the dissolution of nonpolar solutes in nonpolar solvents possible are primarily [Van der Waals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) forces, also known as London dispersion forces. These forces arise from temporary fluctuations in electron distribution, leading to the creation of temporary dipoles in molecules. In a nonpolar solvent, these temporary dipoles induce similar temporary dipoles in neighboring solvent molecules. This induces a weak attraction between the solute and solvent molecules, allowing them to mix and dissolve.

Also [hydrophobic interactions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/hydrophobic-interaction) play a role in the dissolution of nonpolar solutes in nonpolar solvents. Hydrophobic interactions occur due to the tendency of nonpolar molecules to minimize contact with polar molecules, such as water. This can lead to the aggregation of nonpolar molecules in a nonpolar solvent, effectively allowing them to dissolve and disperse.